# Edit specific field data in txt file base on other field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a txt file named BookDB.txt which has the following data.

```
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
```

It is separated with a delimiter such that its group by Title, Author, Price, QtyLeft and QtySold.

Here is my question, I am required to prompt for input of the Title and Author, then it will check through BookDB.txt to find the line of that book and edit its price. How do i actually go about doing it? This is what i've done so far

```
read -p $'Title: '  updatetitle
read -p $'Author: '  updateauthor

#check if book exist in BookDB.txt
if grep -Fq "${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}" BookDB.txt
then
    read -p $'NewPrice: '  newPrice
    #This is the part i'm stuck
else
     echo "Book does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
if grep -Fq "${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}" BookDB.txt
then
    read -p $'NewPrice: '  newPrice
    awk -F: -v title="$updatetitle" -v auth="$updateauthor" -v price=$newPrice '$1==title && $2==auth{$3=price;}1' OFS=":" BookDB.txt >> BookDB.txt_tmp
    mv BookDB.txt_tmp BookDB.txt
else
     echo "Book does not exist"
fi
```

Using `awk`, the 3rd field is updated and the contents are copied in a temporary file which is then renamed back to the original file.

The parameters updatetitle,updateauthor and newPrice  are passed to `awk` using the `-v` option. The 1st(`$1`) field is checked against updatetitle and the 2nd field(`$2`) is checked against updateauthor, and if they both match, the 3rd field is udpated with newPrice (`$3=price`). `1` at the end is to print every line.

**Using sed(GNU)**: (in place of awk and mv above)

```
sed -i "s/\(${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}:\)\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1${newPrice}\3/" file
```

Comment: How it would look like with `sed`?

Comment: Hey Guru, tried out ur method and it works. Thanks! Could u explain a little on -v and '$1==title && $2==auth{$3=price;}1'? Im new to bash. How does it work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
if grep -Fq "${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}" BookDB.txt
then
    read -p $'NewPrice: '  newPrice
    sed -i -e "s/${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}:[^:]\+/${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}:${newPrice}/g" BookDB.txt
else
     echo "Book does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Hey, tried your method and works. Thanks! But quick question, im really new to bash so could u explain a little on how did that code work out?

Comment: Sorry, absent just now. All the code is the same except the additional line which is a `Stream EDitor` command. The `-i` option indicates inplace modification, `-e "s/${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}:[^:]\+/${updatetitle}:${updateauthor}:${newPrice}/g"` is the action taken. In the action `s/A/B/g`, we substitue pattern `A` with string `B` *G*lobally. Variable substitution is achieve by bash, so you can add shell variables into your action but remember quoted with `"`. That's it!